# Test Manager for Trac questions

Tags: testing, trac

I'm looking for a way to better manage a list of test cases within Trac.  The [Test Manager plugin for Trac](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TestManagerForTracPlugin) seems to be the obvious choice.

Anyone have experience, comments and/or concerns with the Test Manager plugin for Trac?

We've also looked at [Testuff](http://www.testuff.com/), which has an awesome "Test Runner" app that integrates with Trac for creating tickets.  However, it stores all of the test cases, labs, etc on their servers.  I'd really like to have a single destination for documentation, tickets and tests (i.e. Trac).

We're using SnagIt for screen capture and annotations today.  We're looking at the Problem Steps Recorder in Windows.  We'd like to find something that can send captures to Trac, similar to the Testuff-Trac integration.

Any suggestions for an app that can capture video/images with each mouse click and key press logged?  BONUS: Attach capture(s) into a new Trac ticket.

Answer (score 0):

For capturing movies and uploading into Trac, try http://www.bbtestassistant.com/

For single screen captures, annotation and uploading into Trac, try http://fat-bug.com

I have also written a plugin for Cropper, http://cropper.codeplex.com/, that will let you upload images but it does not support annotations before hand like fat bug.  Let me know if you want a copy of that.

Answer (score 0):

We used Test Manager Plugin For Trac in one of my previous projects and I can say that it worked fine for us. It provides bidirectional traceability between Test Cases and user stories, support test plans (which in my point of view are execution plans but incorporated with wiki page become test plan) and it also as most of the Trac plugins allow to be customized in order to satisfy the process needs.